# Extend robotic arm with wrist rotation

Tags: robotic-arm

I got an [OWI Robotic arm](http://www.owirobots.com/store/catalog/robotic-arm-kits-and-accessories/owi-535pc-robotic-arm-kit-with-usb-pc-interface-138.html), but was slightly disappointed at it having only horizontal position for gripper. What would be the easiest way to extend with gripper/wrist rotation, i.e. 6th degree of freedom?

[image: OWI Robotic arm]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot do that. I have a OWI robotic arm too.  I purchased it for my semester project to demonstrate inverse kinematics for 5 DOF. 
Since OWI is designed as a toy to play with, we cannot expect more from it. It just does basic movements to give us an idea how a robotic arm functions. 
If you are looking for a 6DOF arm i suggest you purchase another 6 DOF arm like this arm by [DFRobot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R5CCJ2S).

[image: DFRobot 6 DOF Robotic Arm]

Comment: To convert vertical into horizontal without additional motors, at least there is bell crank or four-bar linkage

Comment: But, it is not worth modifying. If you are planning for a serious experiment with a 6 DOF robotic arm, it is better to purchase a manufactured arm instead of modifying OWI. The limitations in OWI's structure and motors will not give you a good result while trying to give custom degree of freedom. It is supposed to be used as it is. However, you can only make use out of it for 4-DOF projects. Based on my experience, i really dont want you to waste your time on modifying OWI

Comment: I did a similar simulation using SolidWorks:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crJXUlzJ918